# Contact Form 7 not redirecting upon email sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a form that I am trying to have redirect to `http://www.example.com` upon successfully sending an email. I have tried different approaches including `on_sent_ok` in the additional settings as well as

```
if(jQuery('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').length > 0)   
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

in my JavaScript, but that does not seem to work as well.

Edit: I forgot to mention that upon the user clicking submit, I do a prevent default in order to do some calculations and generate a PDF. Once it is all done I do

```
$("form.wpcf7-form").unbind('submit').submit();
```

to allow the submission to happen. Could this be causing any issues with the redirection?

Comment: I don't know anything about Contact Form 7 but shouldn't it have some setting to redirect after submission? I found this in the docs: http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/. **Edit:** oh nvm, I just noticed that you said it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the format for the on_sent_ok correctly? It should be `on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';"` according to the link I posted.

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact Form 7 made a ajax call. After success the element is inserted. Then you can check if element exist:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  if (jQuery('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').length) {
    alert(1);
   //window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  }
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much! Solved my problem I've been having for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe I'm writing late, but this code will definitelly will do the job. (If you're working in wordpress). I'm using it so far and it's working normally.

Remember to place this code at your functions's file and as final note remember that you must use one or the other, not both...!

```
add_action('wp_head', 'RedirectsCF7');
// Start of function.
function RedirectsCF7() {

    if(is_page("contact-page-or-whatever-page-name-is")) {

    echo "<script>document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {location = 'https://www.google.com/';}, false);</script>";

    }
}

// Or simply add this code to all pages, like this.
    if(!is_admin()) {

    echo "<script>document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {location = 'https://www.google.com/';}, false);</script>";

    }
}
```

Reference [here](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)